# Machine intelligence raises girl on spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel

I’m trying to remember the title of a science fiction novel. I thought it was Star Child by Hogan or Logan but can’t find it in references.

The book began with a machine intelligence on an extremely old spaceship that grows a girl, I believe from a sample it discovers somewhere on the vast ship. There are several machine intelligences with wildly different personalities who debate what to do. They eventually create a physical being, an android, to take care of the physical being. Later they grow some of the other samples. Soon there is a ship full of diverse children with the first girl, I think her name was Anya, helping to raise the younger ones. The ship eventually lands on a planet (its original destination?) inhabited by a medieval culture. The robots are mistaken for armored knights and attacked. Their bow weapons are ineffective against metal beings, but can kill flesh and blood.

I thought the book was very interesting because it investigates the ideas of intelligence, humanity, even religion. Unfortunately I loaned my copy to a friend >20yrs ago. Any help recalling the title would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the title of a story with a little girl alone on a generation ship with a robot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158554/what-is-the-title-of-a-story-with-a-little-girl-alone-on-a-generation-ship-with)

Comment: @DoscoJones The answer to this question has not been accepted yet.

Answer (score 17):

The clues you have suggest you might be thinking of [*Star Child*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31957) (1998) by James P. Hogan.

[image: Cover of "Star Child" showing a grey-skinned Kort holding Taya in his left arm as he walks down a ship corridor.]

Quoting from a [review on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/784803588):

> **A young girl, Toya[sic], lives aboard an interstellar ship, Merkon. Her only friend is Kort, a humanoid robot** who patiently explains to her that the ship is in interstellar space and that they are en-route to a star, but that it will take a long time to get there. It appears that Toya is the only human on board. The machines apparently became self-aware during the journey and **evolved several independent minds; a Mystic, a Thinker, a Scientist and a Sceptic**, who together managed to deduce that someone had built them and from that discovered the record of DNA codes from which they built Toya.
>
> However, Toya is not strictly speaking, alone. Not only does she have Kort, but a humanoid robot who is a an amalgam of the four original minds, but **also another fifty children, babies in stasis, whom Kort awakes** for Toya to mother and train.

I don't have the book in front of me to provide direct quotes, but I'll try to dig it up tomorrow.

Comment: It sounds like this may have inspired the film *[I Am Mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Mother)*.

Comment: This actually reminds me a little bit of the ending scene of The Toll by Neal Shusterman